# RecurrenceTable with multiple vectors

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to do numerical calculations by recursion with vectors.  I wrote a test code with single variable using 2 ODE's as shown below,

```
Clear[x, y, t, h, NN, cpustart, cpuend, sol1];
resolution = 0.1; tmax = 1;
cpustart = TimeUsed[];
nn = IntegerPart[tmax/resolution];
With[{h = resolution, NN = nn, x0 = 0, y0 = 1, t0 = 0}, 
ans = Transpose[
RecurrenceTable[{x[k + 1] == x[k] + h 1/(x[k]^2 + y[k]^2)^(0.5), 
  y[k + 1] == y[k] + h 4/(x[k]^2 + y[k]^2)^(0.5), 
  t[k + 1] == t[k] + h , x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, t[0] == t0}, {x, 
  y, t}, {k, 0, NN}]]];
ListPlot[ans[[1, All]], DataRange -> {0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Yellow, PointSize[0.03]}]
ListPlot[ans[[2, All]], DataRange -> {0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Yellow, PointSize[0.03]}]
cpuend = (TimeUsed[] - cpustart)
sol1 = cpuend;
```

Then I converted the above code to use vectors as shown below,

```
Clear[x1, y1, x2, y2, z1, z2, r1, r2, t, h, NN, cpustart, cpuend, 
 sol2];
r1 = {x1, y1, z1};
r2 = {x2, y2, z2};
resolution = 0.1; tmax = 1;
cpustart = TimeUsed[];
nn = IntegerPart[tmax/resolution];
With[{h = resolution, NN = nn, r10 = {0, 0, 0}, r20 = {1, 1, 0}, 
  t0 = 0}, ans = Transpose[RecurrenceTable[{
  r1[k + 1] == r1[k] + h r1[k]/(r1[k] . r2[k])^(0.5),
  r2[k + 1] == r2[k] + h 4 r2[k]/(r1[k] . r2[k])^(0.5),
  t[k + 1] == t[k] + h , r1[0] == r10,
  r2[0] == r20, t[0] == t0}, {r1, r2, t}, {k, 0, NN}]]];
ListPlot3D[ans[[1, All]], DataRange -> {0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Yellow, PointSize[0.03]}]
ListPlot3D[ans[[2, All]], DataRange -> {0, tmax}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Yellow, PointSize[0.03]}]
cpuend = (TimeUsed[] - cpustart)
sol2 = cpuend;
```

However, the above code does not work.  I believe its due to wrong definition/use of vectors.

```
RecurrenceTable::dvout: The output function {x1,y1,z1} is not one of the dependent   variables {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},t}.
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if one can get `RecurrenceTable` to treat some dependent variables as vectors, but I will describe another solution using `NestList`. I usually try to stay away from more specialized commands if more basic commands such as `NestList` suffice.

Define the recurrence as a map:

```
recurrence[h_][{r1_,r2_,t_}]:={
   r1+h*r1/(r1.r2)^(1/2),
   r2+h*4*r2/(r1.r2)^(1/2),
   t+h
};
```

Given data such as

```
resolution=0.1;
r10={0,1,1};
r20={1,1,0};
t0=0;
nn=10;
```

the solution is obtained using

```
NestList[recurrence[resolution],{r10,r20,t0},nn]
```

**Note.** I used a different `r10` than OP to avoid division by zero.

**Note.** To answer OP's actual question (*Where I am wrong?*) note that OP did something similar to the following simplified example:

```
RecurrenceTable[{
   {x1,x2,x3}[k+1]=={x1,x2,x3}[k]+{1,2,3},
   {x1,x2,x3}[0]=={4,5,6}},
   {{x1,x2,x3}},{k,0,2}]
```

In particular, the second argument `{{x1,x2,x3}}` is not just a symbol or list of symbols, but a list of vectors of symbols. Nothing in the current version of the [documentation of `RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) suggests that something like this is supported, hence the error.